# LotusNotes agent writing output to external location

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

Lotus Notes scheduled agent that performs an export of data, but not to the notes server, but to a shared location on the network.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I used to do that in two different steps:

1. Create the file locally on domino server
2. use a sheduled task or cron job to copy the file to the required network destination

Reason why I wanted to have this splitted is that I was able to create a dedicated user for the scheduled task only. This user has to have the rights to run the task on the domino server as well as write access to the network share. Additionally. the agent won't fail in case of an issue with the connectivity to the network share.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the shared location as a drive (on the server side) and write the file to it.

Comment: we're looking to avoid that scenario as so many approvals are required.

Comment: There are often security issues with this approach, especially if running on Windows 2008.